# jquery script doesn't work in asp.net masterpage when form tag is present but script works when i remove it. What is causing this?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, webforms

Here is my markup. To briefly explain the main-nav__list is hidden on handhleds and the script toggles class main-nav__list--is-visible when u select the hamburger icon. If i take out the form tag right below here with id=form1 and runat server everything works fine. With it in there the script briefly slidetoggles element. It works the same if i use toggleclass or slidetoggle. It works for a split second in toggle class then dissapears. I have tried putting it in different areas of page, outside and inside of form tag and external but it always works the same if form tag is in there. I need to keep runat server form tag am assuming. I am a noob when it comes to asp.net. What is causing this and what can i do to solve this?

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
<header role="banner" id="header">
    <nav role="navigation" class="main-nav grid-container">
        <a href="../Default.aspx" class="logo"></a>
        <ul class="main-nav__list">
            <li class="main-nav__list__item"><a></a></li>
            <li class="main-nav__list__item"><a></a></li>
            <li class="main-nav__list__item"><a></a></li>
            <li class="main-nav__list__item"><a></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <button class="btn--hamburger-icon">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </button>
</header>
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

</form>
```

here is the script. i only put script on page at bottom to make it easier to test for me.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn--hamburger-icon").on("click", function () {
            $(".main-nav__list").toggleclass("main-nav__list--is-visible");
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is the relevant css.

```
     .main-nav__list--is-visible {
    display: flex !important;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
   }

       .logo {
      width: auto;
      height: rem-calc(50px);
      padding: rem-calc(0 10px);
      font-family: 'Metal Mania', cursive;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: rem-calc(50px);
      color: #ffffff;
      z-index: 9999;}

     .main-nav {
       position: relative;
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       flex-wrap: nowrap;
   @include respond-to(desktops) {
    position: static;
    justify-content: space-between;
      }
   }

  .main-nav__list {
      position: absolute;
      top: rem-calc(50px);
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width: 100%;
      height: rem-calc(200px);
      text-align: center;
      display: none;


@include respond-to(desktops) {
    position: static;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
     }
   }

 .main-nav__list__item {
    display: flex;
    height: rem-calc(50px);
    background-color: $nav-background-color;
    width: 100%;
   @include respond-to(desktops) {
      width: auto;
         }
     a {
        color: #ffffff;
        line-height: rem-calc(50px);
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
     @include respond-to(desktops) {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0 14px 0 14px;
    }

    &:hover {
        background-color: $nav-hover-color;
         }
      }
  }
 .btn--hamburger-icon {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: rem-calc(5px);
      right: rem-calc(2px);
      width: rem-calc(39px);
      height: rem-calc(39px);
      padding: rem-calc(1px 4px);
      background: $nav-background-color;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
@include respond-to(desktops) {
    display: none;
}
& > div {
    width: rem-calc(17px);
    height: rem-calc(3px);
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: rem-calc(3px 0);
    text-align: center;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button submits the form. That is, after your script has executed, the contents of the form are sent to the server and the page is reloaded.

You don't want that, so possible solutions are:

1. Give the button `type="button"` so that it no longer submits. (Buttons are `type="submit"` by default)

   ```
   <button class="btn--hamburger-icon" type="button">
   ```
2. `return false` at the end of the click handler function to keep the button from performing its default action

   ```
   $(".btn--hamburger-icon").on("click", function () {
       $(".main-nav__list").toggleclass("main-nav__list--is-visible");
       return false;
   });
   ```

By the way, this problem is not specific to ASP.NET; it occurs in plan HTML/Javascript environments too.